# How to build an anchor in CodeIgniter where you want to change a variable that is already present in the URI?

Tags: codeigniter, url, parameters, get, anchor

Normally I would just use URL GET parameters but CodeIgniter doesn't seem to like them and none of the URL helper functions are designed for them, so I'm trying to do this the 'CodeIgniter way'.

I would like to build a page where the model can accept a number of different URI paramters, none necessarily present, and none having to be in any particular order, much like a regular URL query string with get parameters.

Let's say I have the following url:

```
http://example.com/site/data/name/joe/
```

Here not including the controller or the method there would be one parameter:

```
$params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1);
print_r($params);
// output
array( [name] => [joe] )
```

If I wanted 'joe' to change to 'ray' I could do this:

```
echo anchor('name/ray');
```

Simple enough but what if there are more parameters and the position of the parameters are changing? Like:

```
http://example.com/site/data/town/losangeles/name/joe/
http://example.com/site/data/age/21/name/joe/town/seattle
```

Is there a way to just grab the URL and output it with just the 'name' parameter changed?

**Edit:** As per landons advice I took his script and set it up as a url helper function by creating the file:

```
application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php
```

Basically I rewrote the function current_url() to optionally accept an array of parameters that will be substituted into the current URI. If you don't pass the array the function acts as originally designed:

```
function current_url($vars = NULL)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    if ( ! is_array($vars))
    {
        return $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
    else
    {
        $start_index = 1;

        $params = $CI->uri->uri_to_assoc($start_index);

        foreach ($vars as $key => $value)
        {
            $params[$key] = $value;
        }

        $new_uri = $CI->uri->assoc_to_uri($params);
        return $CI->config->site_url($new_uri);
    }
}
```

It works OK. I think the bottom line is I do not like the 'CodeIgniter Way' and I will be looking at mixing segment based URL's with querystrings or another framework altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `assoc_to_uri()` method to get it back to URI format:

```
<?php

// The segment offset to use for associative data (change me!)
$start_index = 1;

// Parse URI path into associative array
$params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc($start_index);

// Change the value you want (change me!)
$params['name'] = 'ray';

// Convert back to path format
$new_uri = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($params);

// Prepend the leading segments back to the URI
for ($i=1; $i<$start_index; $i++)
{
    $new_uri = $this->uri->segment($i).'/'.$new_uri;
}

// Output anchor
echo anchor($new_uri);
```

I'd recommend wrapping this in a helper function of some sort.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CodeIgniter's built in URI Class? It allows you to select the relevant segments from the URL which you could use to create the anchor. However, unless you created custom routes, it would mean that your methods would need to accept more parameters.

To use the [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html), you would have the following in your method:

```
echo anchor($this->uri->segment(3).'/ray');
```

Assuming /site/data/name are all CodeIgniter specific (/controller/method/parameter)

Now, I think this could be made a lot easier if you were using [routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html). Your route would look like this:

```
$route['site/data/name/(:any)'] = 'site/data/$1';
```

Effictively, your URL can be as detailed and specific as you want it to be, but in your code the function is a lot cleaner and the parameters are quite descriptive. You method would defined like this:

```
function data($name) { }
```

To extend your route to accept more parameters, your route for the the example URL "http://example.com/site/data/age/21/name/joe/town/seattle" you supplied would look like this:

```
$route['site/data/age/(:num)/name/(:any)/town/(:any)'] = 'controller/data/$1/$2/$3';
```

And your function would look like this:

```
function data($age, $name, $town) { }
```